# Unable to Run Python Script In Cron

Tags: python, linux, cron

I have a simple Python script that I am trying to setup as a cron job, but it refuses to run. It does run when I run it by itself calling it as:

```
python script.py
```

I have tried setting my evironment variables in the crontab, but I cant get it to work. My crontab looks like this:

```
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# m h  dom mon dow   command
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/home/netadmin/bin:/home/net/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/b$

*/2 * * * * PYTHONPATH=/user/bin/python /home/net/path-to-script/script.py >>/home/net/out.txt 2>&1
```

Any Ideas on this?

Comment: You can create `.sh` a script that will make everything and run it from cron. I make so. It's much easy

Comment: Not sure how that would look like.

Comment: Just made `.sh` a script that will do all as you do in `crontab`. You can test this script and all is ok - just add it to your cron job

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up two unrelated concepts:

- the Python *interpreter location*, which is the *path to the Python interpreter program* (an executable file somewhere)
- and the *PYTHONPATH*, which is a string indicating search locations (directories) for Python libraries. It is **not** the location of the Python interpreter, but rater a `:`-separated list of directories. If you don't know what it's useful for, don't use it!

If doing `python script.py` works, there is generally no need to tweak the PYTHONPATH. You can obtain the full path to the *Python interpreter* with `which`:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

This will print the absolute path to the *Python interpreter* that you can use in your crontab:

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/script.py >>/home/net/out.txt 2>&1
```

Don't tweak PYTHONPATH if you don't need to. If `script.py` relies on libraries that are not installed on the system, I encourage you to learn & use [virtualenvs](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). It's easy and solves most Python library dependency issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shell script (we'll call it foo.sh for this example) which would look like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
/user/bin/python /home/net/path-to-script/script.py >>/home/net/out.txt 2>&1
```

You need to make foo.sh executable, so you will need to run the following to do that:

```
chmod +x /home/net/path-to-script/foo.sh
```

Finally, you can add the shell script to a cron job by running this (which you seem familiar with):

```
crontab -e
```

Add a line as follows:

```
*/2 * * * * /home/net/path-to-script/foo.sh
```

That should do it, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect, remove PYTHONPATH

```
*/2 * * * * PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python /home/net/path-to-script/script.py >>/home/net/out.txt 2>&1
```

=>

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/net/path-to-script/script.py >>/home/net/out.txt 2>&1
```

It's recommended to use [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) however.

Comment: Also, depending on whether this is the systemwide crontab /etc/crontab or a user's crontab, there might be a missing user column that specifies which user the command is supposed to run under. man crontab is your friend.

Comment: I am already using the shebang at the top of my python scrip and I have set it to the way that you have it in listed but it still is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting environment variable **PYTHONPATH**, you can run it directly also I believe path for python would be **usr** instead of **user** try this

```
*/2 * * * * cd /home/net/path-to-script ; /usr/bin/python script.py >>/home/net/out.txt 2>&1
```