# How to find shebang line for anaconda distribution in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, shebang

How do I find what shebang line to use for my anaconda python distribution on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have tried:

`/usr/brb/bin/anaconda/python` from [Python shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50546892/python-shebang-line)

`/usr/bin/python` from [Unable to Run Python Script In Cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104506/unable-to-run-python-script-in-cron), but this gives me the native python which does not have all the packages that I have installed

`/Users/brb/anaconda/bin/python` from http://www.jessicayung.com/automate-running-a-script-using-crontab/

I have also tried `/users/brb/anaconda/bin/python` and `/usr/brb/anaconda/bin/python` thinking the above may be a typo.

I am new to Linux/Ubuntu and someone else set up anaconda on my machine - he knows what he is doing so would have put it in a logical place, but I am not 100% sure where it is located or how to find it.

Comment: Which of these paths actually exist? I would assume `/usr/brb` is not an existing path so you can scratch those.

Comment: Yes, this is true.  Folders are: bin, games, include, lib, local, sbin, share, src.  I get muddled because /home in Nautilus is really /home/brb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/bin/env python` works, but I will leave the question unanswered as would appreciate knowing how to find the shebang line for application x.

I read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix), but don't really understand where things are stored by default in Linux so wouldn't know what to use for something other than python.