# Unable to run python script with cron

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to run a simple python script with cron and I cannot for the life of me get it to work.  I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

I know there are many questions (and answers) on this.  I have looked at a number of them and I still cannot get it to work.

My python script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from tkinter import messagebox
messagebox.showinfo('MessageBox','Hello world!')
```

I have followed [Unable to Run Python Script In Cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104506/unable-to-run-python-script-in-cron) and changed the permissions as follows:

```
chmod +x /home/brb/bugs/projects/cron/hello.py
```

I can successfully run this from the command line as follows:

```
brb@bishop:~$ /home/brb/bugs/projects/cron/hello.py
```

Inside crontab I have tried to execute the script in 2 different ways as follows (every 2 or 3 minutes to try and pin down which one works...)

```
*/2 * * * * /home/brb/bugs/projects/cron/hello.py
*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/env python /home/brb/bugs/projects/cron/hello.py
```

Nothing happens.

I followed http://www.jessicayung.com/automate-running-a-script-using-crontab/ and tried to inspect the error file as follows:

```
cd ../..
cd var/mail 
nano $brb
```

and I observe a message in nano that says

```
[ Directory '.' is not writable ]
```

I am not sure which directory '.' is, perhaps it is var/mail.  In any case, not sure how to make it writable.  I will google chmod some more to get this writable I guess, but that still doesn't solve why cron is not working when it looks like all the examples I've seen...

**EDIT:**

I followed [How to run an X program from outside the X session (e.g. from the console or SSH)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584411/how-to-run-an-x-program-from-outside-the-x-session-e-g-from-the-console-or-ssh) as per the comment from triplee and, not really knowing what I am doing, I attempted to change my display permissions as follows:

```
brb@bishop:~$ export XAUTHORITY=/home/brb/.Xauthority
brb@bishop:~$ export DISPLAY=':0'
```

My cron job is still not work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run an X program from outside the X session (e.g. from the console or SSH)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584411/how-to-run-an-x-program-from-outside-the-x-session-e-g-from-the-console-or-ssh)

Comment: You are not supposed to have write access to `/var/mail` and you are not supposed to edit your mail spool file. `$brb` is probably an empty string anyway. You can `less /var/mail/brb` to read your mailbox, though using a proper mail program is probably more pleasant.

Comment: Thanks.  I read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584411/how-to-run-an-x-program-from-outside-the-x-session-e-g-from-the-console-or-ssh and set the two environment variables as per the accept answer and it still does not work.  I don't believe it is a duplicate question...

Comment: Things you `export` at the prompt are not available to `cron`. See the [Stack Overflow `crontab` tag info page](/tags/crontab/info) for troubleshooting guidelines. This is almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, I will read this.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is twofold:

- cronjob has does not know where it could be displaying a graphical app (which X server or `DISPLAY` to use.

  This can be addressed by making sure `DISPLAY` is set in the environment of you script. Run `echo $DISPLAY` in a terminal running in your X session. `:0` is a very likely it.
- Even if it knows the correct `DISPLAY`, it does (should) not have access to it. If you are running the cronjob under the same user as the one running your target X session. If it is a different user, and it has access to your user's home, you could reuse it's authority file by setting `XAUTHORITY` to point to it.

  You can also export necessary information from your running session (renewed with each session), type this into a terminal there: `xauth list $DISPLAY` and add it for your cron running user: `xauth add displayname protocolname hexkey` (using those three values as returned by `xauth list`.

Comment: Thanks.  I did run echo $DISPLAY and got :0 as you predicted.  When I run xauth list $DISPLAY I get....     bishop/unix:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  cd4b7cc327d6387c3535465f23f1b50b
#ffff#626973686f70#:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  cd4b7cc327d6387c3535465f23f1b50b
Should I add this to the crontab script?  I am not sure about the last part of your answer...  I will also read the link in the comment about and see if this helps me understand, but if you are able to say what I put where, they would help me close of the question.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: In that case, you should run/add: `xauth add bishop/unix:0 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 cd4b7cc327d6387c3535465f23f1b50b` Beware though the actual cookie value changes with each X session (re)start.